# Trouble importing java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, import

I am trying to assign a date to a variable but Date always comes up red with the 'cant find symbol' message in netbeans.

```
package librarycore;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Loan implements java.io.Serializable
{
   private final Date loanDate;

    Loan(Book aBook, Person aBorrower)
    {

        book = aBook;
        borrower = aBorrower;

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        loanDate = dateFormat(new Date());
        returned = false;                
    }
```

If I try to just import the Date class with `import java.util.Date` then Date in the import shows up red with the can't find symbol message.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @IronPirate your import is correct. It's an issue with the IDE. You can try to compile your class from command line using javac.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 7.4. Alboz are you saying that when i finish the program if i compile it outside of Netbeans it should work regardless of what Netbeans says. is there any way to if NetBeans if its at fault. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @IronPirate I said that the import is correct. Not that the all program it is. This line is not correct: loanDate = dateFormat(new Date()); You cannot call the constructor on an instance variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like an idiot.

I'd somehow created a new package in my project called java that contained an class called util that must have ben confusing NetBeans. When I deleted them the problem went away.

Thanks for all your help people

Answer (score 0):

Possible errors:

- `book`, `borrower` and `returned` is not declared
- `DateFormat` usage: `String s = dateFormat.format(new Date());`
- set the current date: `loanDate = new Date();`

If you want to print the `loanDate` formatted:

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(loanDate));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. book and borrower are declared as class attributes but i cut them out to save space when pasting. Ive tried amending DateFormat as you suggested but no difference. The constructor doesnt have a return value just a Boolean variable thats ambiguously called returned (I should probably change that).